ASP.NET Core MVC : how to render TimeSpan with TotalHours
I'm working with TimeSpan in my model. This TimeSpan represent a duration larger than 24hours (ex. 160 hours). I need to display this duration in my view (representing total hours and minutes: "160:00").
I need to display it in an EditorFor or TextboxFor to allow users to manipulate the value.
I see this post:
Binding to a TimeSpan property in ASP.NET Core MVC
but, following the MS documentation, hh format string represents hours and not "TotalHours".
I see also this post: Format TimeSpan greater than 24 hour
but, for me, it's only how to render "TotalHours" as string in the code, not how to render an editable mask in EditorFor() or TextboxFor() in the view.
Thanks for your suggestions and help.

This question is similar to: Format TimeSpan greater than 24 hour. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PeterB I'm just editing my question. thnks.

Is the issue now solved using the workaround that you added? If so, then it's better to put that in an answer and then remove it from the question. It's OK and normal to answer your own question.

---- Suggested Workaround ---

Use bootstrap-duration-picker that display duration based on value in seconds
Change the ViewModel from TimeSpan to Double.
Send TimeSpan.TotalSeconds() to ViewModel
Convert Double from ViewModel to TimeSpan with TimeSpan.FromSeconds()

=> Work as expected

The only comment on this answer is that the question is about total hours and the answer is about total seconds. but with a little adaptation, it could work.

The bootstrap-duration-picker take a value in seconds. This plugin manage the display in total hours (showDays: false)
